# i don't know why In Leetcode, the result of TestCase and the result of Submit are different

Tags: algorithm

i 'm solving the problem. 139. Word Break. but i have met a problem.
i don't know why the result of TestCase and the result of Submit are different

below is my code,
when i submit my code, it say WrongAnswer for the reason.

Input:
"a"
["b"]

Output:
true

Expected:
false

but when i pressed Run Code, there wasn't problem. I can see Accepted.
also in my VScode Editor, no problem.
i think my code works properly
i don't know why always When submitting code, problem occur.

```
let Trie = {};

var wordBreak = function (s, wordDict) {
  buildTrie(wordDict);

  let answer = searchInTrie(s);

  return answer;
};

function buildTrie(wordDict) {
  for (let i = 0; i < wordDict.length; i++) {
    let root = Trie;
    const currentWord = wordDict[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < currentWord.length; j++) {
      if (!root[currentWord[j]]) {
        root[currentWord[j]] = {};
      }
      root = root[currentWord[j]];
    }
    root["*"] = currentWord;
  }
}

function searchInTrie(target) {
  let root = Trie;

  for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    const currentChar = target[i];
    if (root["*"]) {
      root = Trie;
    }
    // console.log(root, currentChar);

    if (!root[currentChar]) {
      console.log(root, currentChar);
      return false;
    }
    root = root[currentChar];
  }
  return true;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(root, currentChar);
```

This statement is adding an extra line of output, which the compiler might consider incorrect. Remove it and then try submitting once.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but in my case, removing log is not my solution..